# UIScrollview displacement while scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I looking to get the displacement of UIScrollView when a user is scrolling, just need the displacement every time it is scrolled. Using this method

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                    withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
             targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{
    NSLog(@"VELOCITY :- %f , %f",velocity.x,velocity.y);
    NSLog(@"inout offset: %@ ",targetContentOffset);
}
```

I can get velocity but still need to know the actual distance in one direction so that displacement is calc properly.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `contentOffset` property will give you this. in the above method `targetContentOffset` will give you the end offset after deceleration and stop. Generally the above method is used to change the end offset to your wish. Other dragging or scrolling delegate method can also be used with just the `scrollView.contentOffset` to calculate the displacement.

`contentOffset.x & contentOffset.y` will give you displacement in x & y directions respectively.

Comment: but still there is some problem....as exact displacement is not shown...i have zoomed to scale :- 2.0 and then recording the displacement and the marker that i need to shift based on scroll displacement is at scale :- 1.0 . now i have divided disp/2 but there is some problem, is it the sum of all displacements because value of contentOffset.x & contentOffset.y is quite high.

Comment: check out the accepted answer for this question. this will give you contentOffset calculation after zooming: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954757/uiscrollview-content-offset-calculation-after-zoom

Comment: Yeah i was able to get that on my own, but practicaaly the problem is still there, here it is :-  NSLog(@"offset :- %f , %f",scrollView.contentOffset.x,scrollView.contentOffset.y);
   // NSLog(@"offset 2 :- %@",&targetContentOffset);
    NSLog(@"Old Position of rect : %f , %f",newRect.center.x,newRect.center.y);
    newRect.center = CGPointMake(newRect.center.x + (scrollView.contentOffset.x)/2,
                                 newRect.center.y + (scrollView.contentOffset.y)/2);
    `
    NSLog(@"New Position of rect : %f , %f",newRect.center.x,newRect.center.y);`code`

Comment: But, acoording what values i m getting for scrollView.contentOffset , seems to be wrong because i am doing only vertical scrolling and its showing displacement in X also. ??? , by the way what's the point of reference it takes

Comment: when you zoom it gets zoomed in all directions. thats whyy it shows the offset in x also. the point of reference would be when its zoom scale is 1.0 and contentOffset is CGPointZero.